# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException while initializing JAXWS consumer

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I'm getting the below exception when the JAXWS Java consumer stub constructor is invoked. When I try via. SOAPUI everything is working fine and able to get correct response. It is a web server to multiple app server (Websphere 7.x clustered) setup. Consumer code looks fine. Provider code is fine, since it works in SOAPUI. There is some problem with Web Server and web server may respond with a HTML rather then XML. App Server doesn't get the request when trying via Java consumer and no logs are there. We tested in local app server without web server setup, it works. Don't know where the problem lies? Anybody can help? I'm using Axis2 that comes with WebSphere for hosting web service. Web Sphere reads annotations in implementation class to deploy web service. Generate WSDL automatically. WSDL Location I've not specified in implementation file, if it specified  not works. No configuration file (web.xml, etc.,) i provide. It is not an HTTPS web service. I'm able to telnet to the web service server and get the WSDL via telnet.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://ip:port/AppName/ServiceName'.: (http://ip:port/AppName/ServiceName%27.:) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:754)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:670)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:224)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.<init>(WSDL4JWrapper.java:156)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:245)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:168)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactory.java:76)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:71)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:67)
at somepackage.servicename.<init>(servicename.java:42)...more are here hidden to maintain confidential
Caused by: 
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://ip:port/AppName/ServiceName'.: (http://ip:port/AppName/ServiceName%27.:) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2315)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2356)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$13.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:745)
at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:742)
... 70 more
Caused by: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2305)
... 75 more  </pre>
```

Comment: Is the SOAP service running under WebSphere, or the client, or both?

Comment: SOAP service Running in WebSphere Provider side. Consumer and provider run in separate WebSphere. Consumer WebSphere is 8.x and Provider is 7.x. I checked later it is app server to app server interaction. Not app server to web server. This is UAT environment. The one I tested from Desktop to app server 7.x is working fine.

Comment: As Bruce told, Putting WSDL and xsd in client side works and not sure whether good approach. It is more good if we get WSDL and xsd dynamically from server. See His comments for more details

Comment: In consumer side there is no soap service running

Comment: What's the WSDL URL that you're using? Does it redirect to something else? Can you paste the client proxy code that is referencing it? Glad you have a workaround, but, like you, I'd *prefer* to minimize manual activity for such things, and I'd *like* to understand why the original approach isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going wrong with wsdl retrieval for you, but if you can extract the wsdl (and any files it imports) from the remote service and just package them with your client directly, that will avoid retrieving the wsdl from the remote service for each invocation, which besides not working in your case, also degrades performance.  Your client wsdllocation would change to file:///(something).    If you're using a  developer tool like RAD or WDT, it has an option to automatically retrieve the wsdl and package it with the client.

Comment: It worked but is it a good approach? I used jax-ws-catalog.xml and put wsdl and xsd in MANIFEST-INF directory. WSDL using XSD that XSD is importing another XSD.

Comment: If later on there was a breaking change in the remote wsdl, the client might get a less informative error message.  But most clients would still be broken by such a change even if the wsdl is remote.

Comment: A related approach is the -clientJar option for wsimport. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwbs_wsimport.html